# d3js: click event in reusable chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, mouseclick-event

I have a reusable chart that works fine. I added the following simple code to the reusable chart expecting that it would add click listener to all the charts created by it.

```
d3.cloudshapes.barChart = function module() {
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 20},
        width = 500,
        height = 500,
        gap = 0,
        ease = "bounce";
    var svg;


    // Define the 'inner' function: which, through the surreal nature of JavaScript scoping, can access
    // the above variables. 
    function exports(_selection) {
        _selection.each(function(_data) {
            var chartW = 60,
                chartH = 60;

        var test_data = _data.value;

            var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(test_data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
                    .rangeRoundBands([0, chartW], 0.1);

            var y1 = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, 36])
                    .range([chartH, 0]);

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        // If no SVG exists, create one - and add key groups:
            if (!svg) {
                svg = d3.select(this)
                     .append("svg")
             .attr("width", width)
             .attr("height", height)
                     .classed("chart", true);
                var container = svg.append("g").classed("container-group", true);
                container.append("g").classed("chart-group", true);
        container.attr({transform: "translate(" + 60*_data.row + "," + 60*_data.col + ")"});
        container.on("click", click);

            }

        // Transition the width and height of the main SVG and the key 'g' group: 
            svg.classed("chart", true).transition().attr({width: width, height: height});
           var container = svg.append("g").classed("container-group", true);
        container.append("g").classed("chart-group", true);
        container.attr({transform: "translate(" + 60*_data.row + "," + 60*_data.col + ")"});

        container.on("click", click);

            function click()  {
                console.log("I got clicked");
            }

        // Define gap between bars: 
            var gapSize = x1.rangeBand() / 100 * gap;

        // Define width of each bar: 
            var barW = x1.rangeBand() - gapSize;

            // Select all bars and bind data:  
            var bars = svg.selectAll(".chart-group")
                        .selectAll(".bar")
                        .data(test_data);

        bars.enter().append("rect")
            .classed("bar", "true")
            .attr({
                width: barW,
                x: function (d) {                   
                    return x1(d.x) + gapSize / 2; },
                y: function(d) { return y1(d.y); },
                height: function(d) { return chartH - y1(d.y); }
        })
            .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.x); });



        });
    }
```

But the click function works just for the last instance of graph rendered by the reusable chart. How can a click listener added to each graph rendered by the reusable chart ??

A simpler version is here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9T5z/). I want to add a zoomed popover bar chart `svg` on clicking on little bar charts. I think the problem is with dynamically created `div` because when I tried creating charts in predefined `div` than the click function works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Are you running this code inside the component?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff edited the code; `container` is appended to SVG to create elements within a graph.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff what do you mean by 'inside the component' ?

Comment: Well presumably you have something that looks like `element.call(component)` to render the component. Does this call also establish the event listener or do you need to run separate code for that?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff It would establish an event listener, but before implementing that I was trying some simple console logs to see how things work.

Comment: Well it's really crucial to see how exactly it's implemented to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have added code for reusable chart in the question. I cannot put the whole thing in fiddle as it is a lot of code with database backend.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you would be passing an array of arrays to that component and it draws a bar chart for each array? It looks like the selectors in there are accessing the elements created for earlier bar charts, which is probably not what you want. The code to establish the event listeners looks ok to me though.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes, I am passing an array of arrays that draws each bar chart and then transforms and translates it the desired location in the `svg` using row and col. The click function works just for the last instance of chart created, so it could be that the selector is just accessing the last chart. How would you recommend fixing this problem of selectors ??

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have uploaded a simpler working fiddle to the question. Any advices on how to fix the issue ?

Comment: To be honest, I think that a refactoring is needed here. In my opinion, your chart component should draw exactly one bar chart. Then you can append multiple elements and call the component multiple times with the different data. This should also solve the problem of the click handler.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff But I am already appending a new `chart-group` and `container-group` element for each bar chart.

Comment: My point is that encapsulating each bar chart on its own would make it easier to figure out what exactly you're working with. At the moment, you're appending elements all over the place and these are affected by elements appended previously. It's quite difficult to figure out what's going on there.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am sorry, but I am really confused now. If I run reusable chart with two predefined `div`s i.e. one for each chart, the click function works fine for both the charts. It works fine even with both charts displayed in one predefined `div`. So, wouldn't it be an error with `div`s that are created dynamically ? I have to create `div`s dynamically as the number of charts depend on the data uploaded from user end and is not fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I think that it would be better to do the iteration to add several charts not inside the component.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4KF4/) should make things clearer. click function works fine for both the charts, but as soon as the `document.getElemet()` line is uncommented, the same problem occurs again. This is what I was trying to say that if I draw charts on predefined `div` they work fine, but dynamically created `div` creates the error.

Comment: Sorry -- what does the `getElement()` line have to do with this? It looks to me like that generates a completely unrelated error.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am sorry to trouble you again, but I am really stuck with this click function. I have changed the reusable chart to draw  whole chart in one call to the function (as mentioned by you), but the click function still works just for the second chart. This is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s7tZ/). Could you please have a last look on it ??

Comment: In your latest jsfiddle none of the charts seem to trigger a click event handler for me.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff That's strange, it works for the second chart on my machine. Thanks for checking anyways !!

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the `svg` variable is causing the problem. In your code, the `svg` variable value is shared throug all the instances of your reusable function. You probably want to use `enter()` to create the SVG element and the inner components, and add the `click` listener to the component. The `svg` variable should be defined inside the `exports` function.

```
// rest of the code...
function exports(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {

        // Select the SVG element
        var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll('svg').data([data]);

        // Create the SVG element on enter, set it's size
        svg.enter().append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

        var component = svg.selectAll('g.component').data([data]);

        // Create the component group on enter and set its attributes
        component.enter().append('g');

        // Add other elements...

        // click listener
        component.on('click', function(d) {
            // click callback.
        });


    });
}
```

Comment: I want to have one `svg` for all the little bar charts. I think the problem is with dynamically created `div` because when I tried the creating multiple charts within one predefined `div`, click function for all the charts works fine. I have attached a working fiddle. Any help would be much appreciated !